# Deuteron problem

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why is I=1 for a deuteron(nucleus of a deuterium)?

A deuteron has 1 proton and 1 neutron and if we go by shell model of nucleus, both of them would fit in 1s1/2 state and according to convention, this would make I=1/2 for a deuteron.
I know that I stands for total angular momentum of a nucleus which is also known as nuclear spin and is given by I(vector)=L(vector)+S(vector)